Degenerate Dimension/Keys and Reference tables
All, what are the best practices for handling degenerated Keys/dimensions in RAW data vault??
also how to handle Xref, Lookups or static tables (One time load) designing RAW data vault, they should be considered as Hub or Reference?
Not sure how to implement.
